# javascript mousewheel image scroll

Tags: javascript, image, scroll, mousewheel

I am trying to make pictures scroll vertically on mousewheel.
How to make not to scroll back when it is on start point, from first to the last picture, and not to scroll further when it is on last picture?

```
var myimages=[
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0137.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0138.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0139.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0140.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0141.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0142.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0143.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0144.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0145.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0146.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0147.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0148.jpg",
            "https://d248fncte96e1e.cloudfront.net/xs/0149.jpg"                
        ]

        var slideshow=document.getElementById("slideshow")
        var nextslideindex=0

        function rotateimage(e){
            var evt=window.event || e //equalize event object
            var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta //delta returns +120 when wheel is scrolled up, -120 when scrolled down
            nextslideindex=(delta<=-120)? nextslideindex+1 : nextslideindex-1 //move image index forward or back, depending on whether wheel is scrolled down or up
            nextslideindex=(nextslideindex<0)? myimages.length-1 : (nextslideindex>myimages.length-1)? 0 : nextslideindex //wrap image index around when it goes beyond lower and upper boundaries
            slideshow.src=myimages[nextslideindex]
            if (evt.preventDefault) //disable default wheel action of scrolling page
                evt.preventDefault()
            else
                return false

        }

        var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

        if (slideshow.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
            slideshow.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, rotateimage)
        else if (slideshow.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
            slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, rotateimage, false)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if there is a next image in the array. That means adding an if statement before setting the image and, if it's undefined, going back to the first image and resetting the counter

```
var slideshow=document.getElementById("slideshow")
var nextslideindex=0

function rotateimage(e){
        var evt=window.event || e //equalize event object
        var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta //delta returns +120 when wheel is scrolled up, -120 when scrolled down
        nextslideindex=(delta<=-120)? nextslideindex+1 : nextslideindex-1 //move image index forward or back, depending on whether wheel is scrolled down or up
        nextslideindex=(nextslideindex<0)? myimages.length-1 : (nextslideindex>myimages.length-1)? 0 : nextslideindex //wrap image index around when it goes beyond lower and upper boundaries
        if(myimages[nextslideindex] != undefined) {
            slideshow.src=myimages[nextslideindex]
        }
        else {
            slideshow.src=myimages[0]
            nextslideindex = 0;
        }
        if (evt.preventDefault) //disable default wheel action of scrolling page
            evt.preventDefault()
        else
            return false

}
```

**Edit**

Now I understand what you're going for based on the jsFiddle and comment. You want to simply prevent it from going past the end. You can do that quite easily [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/Kv4yB/1/) by simply adding an if statement and removing the line

```
nextslideindex=(nextslideindex<0)?...
```

The updated function

```
var slideshow = document.getElementById("slideshow");
var nextslideindex = 0;

function rotateimage(e){
    var evt = window.event || e; //equalize event object
    var delta = evt.detail? evt.detail * (-120) : evt.wheelDelta; //delta returns +120 when wheel is scrolled up, -120 when scrolled down
    nextslideindex = (delta <= -120)? nextslideindex + 1 : nextslideindex - 1 //move image index forward or back, depending on whether wheel is scrolled down or up

    if(myimages[nextslideindex] != undefined) {
        slideshow.src = myimages[nextslideindex];
    }
    else {
        // You can put an alert or something here if you'd like
    }

    if (evt.preventDefault) //disable default wheel action of scrolling page
        evt.preventDefault();
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: It's a rough guess at what you are looking for. I need more code for it to work perfectly, perhaps a live example

Comment: Here is a working live example, I need to stop going further when i reach on the last picture (going back is allowed), and not going back from the first picture to the last.

http://jsfiddle.net/dzadze/Kv4yB/

Comment: @DzaDze Anything else I can help with?